# Как добавить редактирование текста Django?

Tags: python, django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добавить в джанго проект(на свой сайт) подобную панель редактирования текста? Можно ли вообще, а если да, то с помощью какого модуля ? Как можно обозвать эту штуку ? Заранее безумно благодарен!

Comment: Это называется wysiwyg-редактор - [django-ckeditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor) и [django-tinymce](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [simplemde](https://simplemde.com/). 
Пример использования можно найти [здесь](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/10/09/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-6.html#adding-markdown).